# Is it possible to embed JavaScript packages in a JSF frontend

Tags: javascript, java, npm, jsf, codemirror

I'm involved in finding an embeddable, lightweight Groovy IDE for an application that uses a JSF frontend. My issue here being no solutions are written in JSF (shocker). Is it possible to embed a JS solution into a JSF frontend? The two providers I'm looking at are CodeMirror and Ace, both are published as NPM packages making me believe there's no solution here. Still figured I'd ask. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to embed your JavaScript when you can load it using a script tag?

Comment: http://primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/monacoEditor.jsf

Comment: @ControlAltDel will that allow me to load its dependencies? I've thought about it but wasn't sure this was going to work given the size of the packages.

Comment: @JasperdeVries great idea if it had support for Groovy. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: So, upvote here https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/129